# How to export registry key in C++

Tags: c++

I need help for export a registry key in C++.

```
   cmd = "  reg.exe export \"HKLM\\software\\Far manager\" \"C:\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.reg\"   ";
   // printf("cmd = %s\n", cmd); 
     system(cmd);
```

The code does not work, because a name "Far manager" contains a space and show me "ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value."

But if I use the name without a space, for example "Mozilla" the program works great.

I am trying to use "Far%20%manager" and Far%backspace%manager, but it does not work too.

But if I write command in cmd (`reg.exe export "HKLM\software\Far manager" "%userprofile%\\Desktop\\test.reg"`) it works great.

Comment: That code looks fine. I expect that the real problem is registry redirection. Is your machine a 64 bit OS? Is your process 32 bit? In which case, registry redirection is the issue.

Comment: You'll probably want to just use the Windows API to do this. [This is the Windows API reference for registry access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724871(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I use a 64 bit OS, but Far manager is 64bit too.

WinAPI  export registry keys in a binary format, but I need a .reg file.

Answer (score 2):

If you have any special characters or spaces in your call to `system()`, you must wrap the entire command in an extra set of double quotes (i.e. `\"`). For your example:

```
cmd = "\"reg.exe export \"HKLM\\software\\Far manager\" \"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.reg\"\"";
system(cmd);
```

Check out [here](http://www.borngeek.com/2011/03/22/calls-to-system-in-windows/) for more info.

Comment: Does not work again.  But if I write command in cmd (reg.exe export "HKLM\software\Far manager" "%userprofile%\\Desktop\\test.reg") it works great.

Comment: @AlexLian Please try the updated answer by adding extra \ before `Users`.